# Java preserve order of methods when compiling

Tags: java, reflection

How can I preserve order of private methods when compiling java classes? I use getDeclaredMethods() and it returns an incorrect order.

Comment: This is not something you can rely on. The javadoc states _The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) says in comments, **you cannot ensure order**. For more details, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585843/java-reflection-getdeclaredmethods-in-declared-order-strange-behaviour) that has already been answered.